# Firestore doc field update in react app giving TypeError unless I refresh first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, typeerror

I have a react app which allows creation of lists for logged in users (groceries, todo, etc) and stores data on firebase.firestore. It's still in development using localhost. If I create a new list, add items to it and immediately edit the item description, I get a TypeError and item description doesn't update in app or firestore. If I pick a different list to display, then click back to new list or refresh the browser before I edit the item description, everything works fine. It just doesn't work if I specifically create new list, add items to it, and immediately try to edit the item description, even though I check firestore before submitting change and the new list and new items are shown to exist.

Any idea why the await checkDoc in the handleSubmit isn't working unless I refresh app in browser first?

I included firestore screenshots before and after app refresh in case it matters. They seem identical to me.

Github repo is branch edit-item
[github repo](https://github.com/PrinceCorwin/iList/tree/edit-item)

error showing in console when I update item description without refreshing:

```
TypeError: u.indexOf is not a function
    at Function.e.ot (prebuilt-67479dbf-318e5a2c.js:878)
    at Bs (prebuilt-67479dbf-318e5a2c.js:14560)
    at e.doc (prebuilt-67479dbf-318e5a2c.js:18281)
    at handleSubmit (EditItem.js:32)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299)
    at react-dom.development.js:8508
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889)
```

EditItem componant with handleSubmit function giving error unless I refresh first:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { db } from '../../hooks/useAuth';

import {
  Button,
  Input,
  Center,
  FormControl,
  Flex,
  Heading,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

const EditItem = ({
  user,
  items,
  setItems,
  setEditItem,
  currentList,
  editItem,
  themeObj,
}) => {
  const checkDoc = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid);

  const [newDesc, setNewDesc] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      console.log(editItem);
      console.log(newDesc);
      console.log(currentList);
      console.log(editItem.id);
      await checkDoc
        .collection(currentList)
        .doc(editItem.id)
        .update({ desc: newDesc });

      const editedList = items.map(item =>
        item.id === editItem.id ? { ...item, desc: newDesc } : item
      );
      setItems(editedList);
      console.log(editedList);
      setNewDesc(`${editItem.desc}`);

      setEditItem(null);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } finally {
    }
  };

  return (
    <Flex w="100%" grow="1" direction="column" p={6}>
      <Center
        mb="1rem"
        borderRadius="lg"
        p={3}
        bg={themeObj.bg}
        color={themeObj.color}
      >
        <Heading size="md">Edit Item Description</Heading>
      </Center>
      <Center
        mb="1rem"
        borderRadius="lg"
        p={3}
        bg={themeObj.bgItem}
        color={themeObj.colorItem}
      >
        {newDesc.length ? newDesc : editItem.desc}
      </Center>
      <form
        label="New Item Description"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
      >
        <FormControl>
          <Input
            required
            variant="outline"
            autoFocus
            // ref={inputRef}
            type="text"
            id="newDesc"
            placeholder="New Item Description"
            required
            value={newDesc}
            onChange={e => setNewDesc(e.target.value)}
          />

          <Button
            variant="solid"
            mt={4}
            type="submit"
            aria-label="Rename List"
            color="white"
            _hover={{
              background: `${themeObj.checkScheme}`,
            }}
            bg="black"
          >
            Update
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="solid"
            mt={4}
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              setEditItem(null);
              setNewDesc(`${editItem.desc}`);
            }}
            aria-label="cancel"
            color="white"
            _hover={{
              background: `${themeObj.checkScheme}`,
            }}
            bg="red"
          >
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default EditItem;
```

Dashboard component (parent to EditItem):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { InputGroup, Stack, Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import EditItem from '../iList/EditItem';
import Loader from '../iList/Loader';
import AddItem from '../iList/AddItem';
import SearchItem from '../iList/SearchItem';
import Content from '../iList/Content';
import Footer from '../iList/Footer';
import { useAuth, db } from '../../hooks/useAuth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const Dashboard = ({
  setAppTheme,
  loaderLoading,
  setLoaderLoading,
  setIsLoading,
  isLoading,
  fetchError,
  setFetchError,
  themeObj,
  currentList,
  setCurrentList,
}) => {
  console.log(currentList);
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [editItem, setEditItem] = useState(null);

  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState('');

  const checkDoc = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid);

  const itemsCollection = db
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection(currentList);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkIfInitialized();
    const getUserPrefs = async () => {
      try {
        const userList = await checkDoc.get();
        setCurrentList(userList.data().currentlist);
        setAppTheme(userList.data().currenttheme);

        setFetchError(null);
      } catch (err) {
        setFetchError(err.message);

        console.log(err.message);
      } finally {
        setLoaderLoading(false);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    getUserPrefs();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {

    const getItems = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await itemsCollection.get();

        const listItems = data.docs.map(doc => ({
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id,
        }));
        setItems(listItems);
        setFetchError(null);
      } catch (err) {
        setFetchError(err.message);
      } finally {
        setLoaderLoading(false);
      }
    };
    getItems();
  }, [currentList]);

  const addItem = async item => {
    const id = items.length ? Number(items[items.length - 1].id) + 1 : 1;
    console.log(id);
    const newItemDate = new Date();
    const dateStr = `${
      newItemDate.getMonth() + 1
    }/${newItemDate.getDate()}/${newItemDate.getFullYear()}`;

    const myNewItem = {
      id: id,
      checked: false,
      desc: item,
      date: dateStr,
    };

    const listItems = [...items, myNewItem];
    setItems(listItems);
    const addedDoc = db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection(currentList)
      .doc(`${myNewItem.id}`);
    await addedDoc
      .set({ desc: myNewItem.desc, checked: false, date: dateStr })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Document successfully written!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error writing document: ', error);
      });
  };

  const handleCheck = async id => {
    const listItems = items.map(item =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item
    );
    setItems(listItems);
    const myItem = items.filter(item => item.id === id);
    console.log(myItem);

    const updatedDoc = db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection(currentList)
      .doc(`${id}`);
    console.log('here');
    await updatedDoc
      .update({
        checked: !myItem[0].checked,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Document successfully updated!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // The document probably doesn't exist.
        console.error('Error updating document: ', error);
      });
  };
  const handleDelete = async id => {
    const listItems = items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    setItems(listItems);
    const deletedDoc = db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection(currentList)
      .doc(`${id}`);
    await deletedDoc
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Document successfully deleted!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error removing document: ', error);
      });
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!newItem) return;
    addItem(newItem);
    setNewItem('');
  };
  const checkIfInitialized = () => {
    const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid);

    docRef
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log('No such document!');
          initializeUserDb();
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error getting document:', error);
      });
  };

  const initializeUserDb = async () => {
    const firstEntry = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid);

    await firstEntry
      .set({
        currentlist: currentList,
        mylists: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('My List'),
        currenttheme: 'default',
        email: user.email,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('currentlist successfully written!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error writing document: ', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {editItem && (
        <EditItem
          items={items}
          setItems={setItems}
          currentList={currentList}
          user={user}
          editItem={editItem}
          setEditItem={setEditItem}
          themeObj={themeObj}
        />
      )}

      {!editItem && (
        <>
          <Stack mb={3} w="100%" p={3}>
            <InputGroup>
              <AddItem
                themeObj={themeObj}
                newItem={newItem}
                setNewItem={setNewItem}
                handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
              />
            </InputGroup>
            <InputGroup>
              <SearchItem
                themeObj={themeObj}
                search={search}
                setSearch={setSearch}
              />
            </InputGroup>
          </Stack>
          <Flex
            w="100%"
            flexDirection="column"
            flexGrow="1"
            justifyContent="flex-start"
            align-items="center"
            overflowY="auto"
          >
            {(isLoading || loaderLoading) && <Loader />}

            {fetchError && (
              <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{`Error: ${fetchError}`}</p>
            )}

            {!fetchError && !loaderLoading && !isLoading && (
              <Content
                setEditItem={setEditItem}
                themeObj={themeObj}
                items={items.filter(item =>
                  item.desc.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
                )}
                handleDelete={handleDelete}
                handleCheck={handleCheck}
              />
            )}
          </Flex>
        </>
      )}

      <Footer bg={themeObj.bg} color={themeObj.color} length={items.length} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

firestore screenshot before refreshing app (I just created "test list" and two items and updating item desc doesn't work)
[image]

firestore screenshot after refreshing app (updating item description works)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

The id of newly created item which I am using to update the doc is a number. But the id on firestore is a string, not a number.

changing the handleSubmit callback from `.doc(editItem.id)` to this fixed it:

```
.doc(`${editItem.id}`)
```